# DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0

Tags: php, html, mysql

i get this kinda error when i try to fetch and display data in a HTML table DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

```
<?php
  require_once 'connection.php';

  try
  {
     $stmt = $cont->prepare("SELECT * FROM  table_de_routage");
     $stmt->execute();

  ?>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table datatable">
         <thead>
         <?php if($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
             <tr>
               <th>adresses IP</th>
               <th>destinations(<?php echo $row['destinations']; ?>)</th>
               <th>routes(<?php echo $row['routes']; ?>) </th>
               <th>active(<?php echo $row['active'];?>)</th>
               <th>holddown(<?php echo $row['holddown'] ;?>)</th>
               <th>hidden(<?php echo $row['hidden'];?>) </th>

             </tr>
             <?php 
               }
              ?>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           <?php while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
             <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['adresses_ip']; ?></td>
             </tr>
           <?php
                }
             }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                  echo $e->getMessage();
                } ?>
```

Comment: aren't table headers just simply hardcoded?, and then the values are inside the `<tbody>` are the ones with the loop

Comment: well table headers need to have a loop to because there are numbers that needd to be shown in them it will be like this 
ex: destination(4346)

Comment: Your json data is invalid from your source. Can you also show your datatable js code?

Comment: i don't have a js code i juste did it with phpmyadmin